# Win8 BitLocker encrypted WD MyPassport drive does not auto-unlock on boot, but does on hot-plug

Tags: windows-8, usb, external-hard-drive, bitlocker

I have a WD MyPassport external USB drive (1 TB), encrypted with BitLocker on Windows 8.  I have the drive set to auto-unlock in its "Manage BitLocker..." right-click properties.

The problem is, it does not actually auto-unlock when I start-up or reboot the PC.

However, the strangest thing is that if I then hot-unplug and hot-plug the drive back in, it does auto-unlock as expected...

Does anyone have any ideas why the drive won't initially auto-unlock on boot?

*Update 1:*

When I first booted-up the PC this morning I was surprised to see the drive auto-unlocked as expected!

However, when I powered-down the PC fully and booted-up again, I could not re-produce the successful auto-unlocking.

I noticed that the light on the back of the MyPassport stays on whilst the PC is "off", so I even tried completely disconnecting the drive when I turned the PC off, and then re-connected it before powering the PC back on again, but I still could not re-produce the successful auto-unlocking.

Comment: Sounds like its working like it should to protect your data from being access by random people.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, but I don't think that's the case, as those "random people" could just unplug and re-plug the drive to bypass that protection. Also, why would an auto-unlock feature work on hot-plug, but not on reboot?